# How am I supposed to use the -audiodev option in QEMU?

Tags: qemu

There is a thread [Fwd: How am I supposed to use the -audiodev option?](https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-discuss@nongnu.org/msg04969.html), but unfortunately it does not contain an answer. I use QEMU on Windows, and when I run my image in QEMU `qemu-system-arm.exe` , I get:

```
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSound
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
sdl: SDL_OpenAudioDevice for playback failed
sdl: Reason: WASAPI can't find requested audio endpoint: Element not found.
sdl: SDL_OpenAudioDevice for playback failed
sdl: Reason: WASAPI can't find requested audio endpoint: Element not found.
audio: Failed to create voice `lm4549.out'
```

So, I want to disable audio completely, and get rid of those messages.

So, I add this (found via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564844/disable-sound-when-using-spice-with-kvm-libvirt) to my command line:

```
-audiodev id=none,driver=none
```

This then results with:

```
audio: Device lm4549: audiodev default parameter is deprecated, please specify audiodev=none
```

As recommended in that thread, I tried:

```
C:\bin\qemu\qemu-system-arm.exe -audio-help
Environment variable based configuration deprecated.
Please use the new -audiodev option.

Equivalent -audiodev to your current environment variables:
(Since you didn't specify QEMU_AUDIO_DRV, I'll list all possibilities)
-audiodev id=dsound,driver=dsound
-audiodev id=sdl,driver=sdl
-audiodev id=none,driver=none
```

Ok, I then try this instead of the above:

```
audiodev=none
```

... and I get:

```
qemu-system-arm.exe: audiodev=none: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

Ok, I try this:

```
-audiodev=none
```

... and I get:

```
qemu-system-arm.exe: -audiodev=none: invalid option
```

So ... how do I set audio device to none in QEMU?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with QEMU 8.2 there is an easy way to configure a default audio backend on the command line (previous versions deprecated the environment variables but the replacement was complicated to use, because it required manual configuration of both the backend and the device that used it).

From the documentation:

> In order to configure a default audio backend, use the -audio command line option without specifying a model; while previous versions of QEMU required a model, starting with version 8.2 QEMU does not require a model and will not create any sound card in this case.

So, just do `-audio none`.